# autonomously flying quadrotor

Tags: ros, quadcopter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all,
i want my quadrotor to fly autonomously.
Are there any examples,what and how i can achieve this goal?
Until now,my quadrotor does only handle the sensordate from IMU(acc,gyro,mag).
IMU-->Kalmanfilter-->PID-Control -->IMU
Are there any ROS solutions,which can be used?written node for sensordatafusion?
Which sensors for autonomous indoor fliying.
would you recommend?

thanks ,greets

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12412/autonomously-flying-quadrotor/) by [hmmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/1556/hmmm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2011-12-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some resources that might get you in the right direction:

- [ROS News: Robots/UAVS](http://www.ros.org/news/robots/uavs/)
- [DIYDrones: Arducopter](http://code.google.com/p/arducopter/wiki/ArduCopter)
- [ROS Robots: AscTec Pelican](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/AscTec)
- [ROS Answers: UAV Simulation Using ROS](http://answers.ros.org/question/101/how-can-uavs-be-simulated-using-ros)
- [ROS Answers: 2D/3D Slam for UAV](http://answers.ros.org/question/865/solutions-for-visually-aided-2d3d-slam-for-uav)
- [ASCTec Pelican Users Mailing List](http://asctec-users.986163.n3.nabble.com/)

You may want to make your question more specific, or else you won't get many answers.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6